# Don't understand how log rules are applied in formula

Tags: logarithms, computational-complexity

On page 148 of *Computational Complexity* by Papadimitriou, it states:

$nc_1^{f(n)} = c_1^{\log(n) + f(n)}$

I understand that I can expand the right part of the formula to $c_1^{\log(n) + f(n)} = c_1^{\log(n)}c_1^{f(n)}$, but then why and how does $c_1^{\log(n)} = n$?

Comment: Just divide both sides by $c_1^{f(n)}$.

Comment: Iff the $\log(n)$ is taken to base $c_1$, i.e. $\log_{c_1}(n)$,then the equality holds.

Comment: I assumed the book was using $\log(n)$ to mean $\log_2(n)$, but it's possible the author wasn't.

Comment: Literally, $c_1^{\log(n)} = n^{\log(c_1)}.$ But $n = c_1^{\log(n)/\log(c_1)}.$ Maybe something written before or after this makes it work out or gives a hint toward the missing piece. For example, $\log(n)/\log(c_1) + f(n)$ is $O(\log(n) + f(n)).$